# Why do the Java tutorials construct Booleans explicitly?

Tags: java

For e.g,

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
   new Boolean(true));
```

[JAXB Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/#binsch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a reason in particular.  That's pretty poor practice, IMO.  Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE do everything you need.

Comment: And `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)` works when you don't know what you need.

Comment: Yeah.  The huge problem with the code above is that it first creates the true literal and then creates a boolean object wrapping the literal :(.  It's like doing 'new String("banana")' for whatever reason.

Comment: That's not the problem - the literal is a primitive, the wrapper an Object. Since the setProperty() method only takes objects, this is necessary, and if you depend on autoboxing, the same thing will happen implicitly. The problem (an insiginficant one here) is that by using the constructor, you create a new Boolean object each time, when two of them (Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE) are all you really need.

Comment: Although it's insignificant here, it's pretty painful when you have millions of 'True' Boolean wrappers, for no reason at all.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, with autoboxing, you can write `true` and it will automatically be converted into `new Boolean(true)` if a `Boolean` object (instead of a `boolean` primitive) is expected.

However, in Java 1.4 and earlier, this is not possible; one had to create the `Boolean` object explicitly. The tutorial you link to is from 2003, and at the time Java 5.0 (a.k.a. Java 1.5) hadn't been released yet.

But even then, as Malaxeur noted, it would have been better to use `Boolean.TRUE`.

Comment: it will actually be converted into Boolean.valueOf(booleanVar), which will never produce new instances but only ever use Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually very strange as the Javadocs for boolean explicitly state it's generally not a good idea http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html. Perhaps that tutorial is somewhat old?

> Constructor Detail Boolean
>
> public Boolean(boolean value)
>
> ```
> Allocates a Boolean object representing the value argument.
>
> Note: It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Unless a new
> ```
>
> instance is required, the static
>   factory valueOf(boolean) is generally
>   a better choice. It is likely to yield
>   significantly better space and time
>   performance.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     value - the value of the Boolean
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when you want a Boolean object, you need the capabilities of a reference type. A method might expect an object, so you pass a Boolean. But probably most important is a Boolean can be null as well as true and false. Say you had a bank with a Boolean transaction succeeded, true for if it did, false for if not. But what if the transaction didn't take place yet? You could set it to false, but that would be confusing as its not accurately describing the data.

This a case where a Boolean comes in handy, but it definitely doesn't mean that its always the right choice. :D

Answer (score 0):

Technically spoken, and as Malaxeur and Thomas argued, one should not use the `Boolean(boolean value)` constructor but use `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` instead. This is even documented in the JavaDoc since version 1.4.2, although the `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` objects are as old as jdk 1.0.1

I do not believe, that JAXB requires unique instances for property values. If that was the unlikely case, there would be an explicit warning to **not** use `Boolean.TRUE`.

The only reason I see: this is a tutorial and the code is improved towards readability. If one reads '`new Boolean(true)`' it is plain clear, that a new Boolean instance is created. '`Boolean.TRUE`' could be, technically spoke, any type and therefore doesn't make clear at first glance, that a Boolean object is needed in this method.